# How to mount a mke2fs image file as a volume in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, disk-volume, kubectl

I am new to k8s, but have been exploring persistent volumes, and the ability to actually limit capacity is only in alpha stage, and needs to be manually enabled to work per: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-capacity/#enabling-storage-capacity-tracking

I'd much rather build a disk image file, such as:

```sh
fallocate -l 50M mytest.img
mke2fs -t ext4 mytest.img
```

And then mount it as a volume in a pod in k8s, but I am not sure how.  I've tried using hostPath, but it failed when trying as a File and a Directory type.  Considering the plethora of volume mounting types, hopefully I just am missing the proper command.

I know I can mount the image somewhere on the host and then point hostPath to the mount, but host mounting shouldn't be required.

Edit: If this isn't possible, can someone suggest an alternative image file type that I can create a limited (but expandable) file that is mountable in k8s?

Comment: I would guess the cheapest way is via the _deprecated_ [flex volume source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#flexvolume) (and [the gory details](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-storage/flexvolume.md#flexvolume)), but surely one of the [existing CSI drivers](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html) meets your needs?

Comment: flex volume, besides being deprecated, is definitely ugly - I'm still looking to see what drivers may meet my needs.  Hopefully someone has done this and can point me to the correct driver/setting for this

Comment: Would raw block volumes work for you? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#raw-block-volume-support

Comment: Block volumes look more cumbersome than volume files - I'd also have to consider how to locate/back up/push files to the block volume in case of a cluster failure.  An image file is simple to back up (part of the host filesystem), and can trivially be mounted to get/set data using built in linux tools.

Comment: I've moved on to Longhorn for volume management, and am able to mount the volumes easily on the host with that.  Leaving this issue open in case someone can find an answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer summing up the current status of this question and the workaround. Posted for better visibility. Feel free to edit and expand it.

Officially [Enabling storage capacity tracking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-capacity/#enabling-storage-capacity-tracking) is still in it's aplha:

> Storage capacity tracking is an alpha feature and only enabled when
> the `CSIStorageCapacity` [feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) and the
> `storage.k8s.io/v1alpha1` API group are enabled. For details on that,
> see the `--feature-gates` and `--runtime-config` [kube-apiserver
> parameters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).

And [flexVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#flexvolume) is deprecated.

The current workaround is to use the [Longhorn](https://github.com/longhorn/longhorn#longhorn):

> Longhorn is a distributed block storage system for Kubernetes.
> Longhorn is cloud native storage because it is built using Kubernetes
> and container primatives.